# Backslash at the end of python string won't be passed through when returned from function

Tags: python, string, directory

I am create a decently complex program and need to add logging to the whole thing. For this I have created a separate file which allows me to easily create a new logger with everything I need for it. Though I am experiencing problem with getting the absolute path of the log folder since the path is returned as a string.

The code here is the code I used to detect which OS it is loaded on, and this works fine, maybe there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do here, but for now I am having issues of the last backslash in the `win32` OS not returning with the entire path

```
def __get_logging_path(log_folder):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + f'\\{log_folder}\\')
    elif sys.platform == 'linux':
        return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) + f'/{log_folder}/'))
    else:
        raise OSError(f'Untested OS: {sys.platform}')
```

I have tried a couple things to replace the following code

```
return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + f'\\{log_folder}\\')
```

Below are all the different option I have tried an none of them have worked so far

```
return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '\\' + log_folder + '\\')
return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + r'\\' + log_folder + r'\\')
return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + f'\\{log_folder}' + r'\\')
```

There is a couple more, but generally just don't work getting

Comment: For starters, you want `join(a, b)`, not `join(a) + b`…!?

Comment: `os.path.sep` could help you I think

Comment: I would recommend `pathlib.Path` for this, it will do all the path conversions between platforms for you

Comment: @deceze I see that I did make a small mistake in that part, but when i try to correct it using `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '\\' + log_folder + '\\'))` it just points to `C:\\Logs`

Comment: You don't add the `'\\'` manually in this case, this is what `join` does. You're changing the behaviour by providing absolute paths.

Comment: You are right. I managed to be completely blind to that, for some reason I was thinking about it as join(a, b) just joining those strings instead of creating a valid path from it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Though I have not figured out what the issue with the original    problem was,*** (old)

I did manage to get it working with the suggestion of using pathlib.Path

By looking in to the documentation a bit I managed to change the code above in to a single line of code

```
Path(__file__).parent.joinpath(log_folder, f'{file_name}.log')
```

This points to a .log file in a subdirectory of the directory of the currently executing file

EDIT:
I recently through comments I have found out my mistake. I managed to miss the fact that `os.path.join()` creates a valid path from given strings, instead of joining the strings together.
Therefore the solution to the original problem seems to be as follows:
`os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), log_folder, log_file))`